# How to sum some elements in R with lapply()

Tags: r, lapply

So, for example, I have a list `x <- 1:10`, and I need to make a list of `x[t]/x[t+n]-1`.

How can I make it with `lapply()`? I don't want to use a for-loop, I want to make it in one command.

Something like: `lapply(1:10, function(i) i/i.prev-1)`. The problem is, how to make i.prev in R `lapply()`?

Comment: `1:10` isn't a list, it is a vector. Try `x[1:(length(x)-1)]/x[2:length(x)]-1`. No need for `lapply`

Comment: @coffeinjunky is it possible to work with .xts? Because 1:10 was an example, I am working with data <- na.omit(cbind(asset1, asset2, asset3)), where assets is Ad(get(getSymbols("IWM", from=from, to=to, src = "yahoo")))

Comment: @coffeinjunky Sorry :(

Comment: @coffeinjunky that's the beauty of `R`. code can be reformulated as  `x[-length(x)]/x[-1] - 1`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk You are right that this is shorter. Making it explicit what is happening is more pedagogical for a beginner, though.

Comment: @AndreyLovyagin If you are working with xts, then please check out the operations you can do with this data structure here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/288218_117e183e74964557a5da4fc5902fc671.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mathematical trick would be to rewrite the `x[t]/x[t+1]` as `exp(log(x[t]) - log(x[t+1]))`, I'm using `rev()` to reverse the `xts` as `diff()` calculates `x[t+1] - x[t]`

```r
exp(rev(diff(log(rev(data))))) - 1
```

Or you could convert it to a `data.frame` :

```r
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data[-nrow(data),]/data[-1,] -1
```

Mind you that the first formula will preserve the `xts` time series type while the second it will be a `data.frame`

Comment: You are the wizard! Thank you!